# Transfer All Data from one magento system to other

Tags: magento2, migration, database-export

I have one Magento system1(2.3.4) system with all the Data

> **Orders**
>
> **Products**
>
> **Customers**
>
> **Reviews**
>
> **Quotes**
>
> **Categories**

Other Magento systems 2(2.3.4), I have to transfer all the data from system 1 to system 2.

Is there any quick way using database table transfer or through pro-grammatically?

Can anyone suggest me what is the better approach for this with the steps?

Thanks!!

Comment: is database on same server? If database not on same server then use mysql dump to export current database and then upload that dump into new db server.

Comment: @Jinesh, yes both database are in same server

Comment: you want to copy whole database into new one?

Comment: @Jinesh, No only the above data which i mentioned, not whole database

Comment: I think you can export product and customer data using magento admin

Comment: @Jinesh, what about orders, and other sales details?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105434/discussion-between-jinesh-and-manjunath).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this for orders:-

> Orders

```
 mysqldump -u root -p password
    sales_bestsellers_aggregated_daily
    sales_bestsellers_aggregated_monthly
    sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly
    sales_creditmemo
    sales_creditmemo_comment
    sales_creditmemo_grid
    sales_creditmemo_item
    sales_invoice
    sales_invoiced_aggregated
    sales_invoiced_aggregated_order
    sales_invoice_comment
    sales_invoice_grid
    sales_invoice_item
    sales_order
    sales_order_address
    sales_order_aggregated_created
    sales_order_aggregated_updated
    sales_order_grid
    sales_order_gst
    sales_order_item
    sales_order_item_gst
    sales_order_payment
    sales_order_status
    sales_order_status_history
    sales_order_status_label
    sales_order_status_state
    sales_order_tax
    sales_order_tax_item
    sales_payment_transaction
    sales_refunded_aggregated
    sales_refunded_aggregated_order
    sales_sequence_meta
    sales_sequence_profile
    sales_shipment
    sales_shipment_comment
    sales_shipment_grid
    sales_shipment_item
    sales_shipment_track
    sales_shipping_aggregated
    sales_shipping_aggregated_order > orderData.sql
```

> Customer

```
mysqldump -u root -p password
 customer_address_entity
 customer_address_entity_datetime
 customer_address_entity_decimal
 customer_address_entity_int
 customer_address_entity_text
 customer_address_entity_varchar
 customer_entity
 customer_entity_datetime
 customer_entity_decimal
 customer_entity_int
 customer_entity_text
 customer_entity_varchar
 customer_grid_flat
 customer_log
 customer_visitor
 persistent_session
 wishlist
 wishlist_item
 wishlist_item_option   > customerData.sql
```

> Review

```
mysqldump -u root -p password
review
review_detail
review_entity_summary
review_store   > reviewData.sql
```

> Products

```
mysqldump -u root -p password
cataloginventory_stock_item
cataloginventory_stock_status
cataloginventory_stock_status_idx
cataloginventory_stock_status_tmp
catalog_category_product
catalog_category_product_index
catalog_category_product_index_tmp
catalog_compare_item
catalog_product_bundle_option
catalog_product_bundle_option_value
catalog_product_bundle_price_index
catalog_product_bundle_selection
catalog_product_bundle_selection_price
catalog_product_bundle_stock_index
catalog_product_entity
catalog_product_entity_datetime
catalog_product_entity_decimal
catalog_product_entity_gallery
catalog_product_entity_int
catalog_product_entity_media_gallery
catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value
catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity
catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_video
catalog_product_entity_text
catalog_product_entity_tier_price
catalog_product_entity_varchar
catalog_product_index_eav
catalog_product_index_eav_decimal
catalog_product_index_eav_decimal_idx
catalog_product_index_eav_decimal_tmp
catalog_product_index_eav_idx
catalog_product_index_eav_tmp
catalog_product_index_price
catalog_product_index_price_bundle_idx
catalog_product_index_price_bundle_opt_idx
catalog_product_index_price_bundle_opt_tmp
catalog_product_index_price_bundle_sel_idx
catalog_product_index_price_bundle_sel_tmp
catalog_product_index_price_bundle_tmp
catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_agr_idx
catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_agr_tmp
catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_idx
catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_tmp
catalog_product_index_price_downlod_idx
catalog_product_index_price_downlod_tmp
catalog_product_index_price_final_idx
catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp
catalog_product_index_price_idx
catalog_product_index_price_opt_agr_idx
catalog_product_index_price_opt_agr_tmp
catalog_product_index_price_opt_idx
catalog_product_index_price_opt_tmp
catalog_product_index_price_tmp
catalog_product_index_tier_price
catalog_product_index_website
catalog_product_link
catalog_product_link_attribute_decimal
catalog_product_link_attribute_int
catalog_product_link_attribute_varchar
catalog_product_option
catalog_product_option_price
catalog_product_option_title
catalog_product_option_type_price
catalog_product_option_type_title
catalog_product_option_type_value
catalog_product_relation
catalog_product_super_attribute
catalog_product_super_attribute_label
catalog_product_super_link
catalog_product_website
catalog_url_rewrite_product_category
downloadable_link
downloadable_link_price
downloadable_link_purchased
downloadable_link_purchased_item
downloadable_link_title
downloadable_sample
downloadable_sample_title
product_alert_price
product_alert_stock
report_compared_product_index
report_viewed_product_aggregated_daily
report_viewed_product_aggregated_monthly
report_viewed_product_aggregated_yearly
report_viewed_product_index    > productData.sql
```

> Categories

```
mysqldump -u root -p password
catalog_category_entity
catalog_category_entity_datetime
catalog_category_entity_decimal
catalog_category_entity_int
catalog_category_entity_text
catalog_category_entity_varchar
catalog_category_flat > categoryData.sql
```

> Url Rewrite

```
mysqldump -u root -p password
    url_rewrite > urlWriteData.sql
```

> Quote

```
 mysqldump -u root -p password
    SALES_FLAT_QUOTE
    SALES_FLAT_QUOTE_ITEM
    SALES_FLAT_QUOTE_ITEM_OPTION
    SALES_FLAT_QUOTE_ADDRESS
    SALES_FLAT_QUOTE_ADDRESS_ITEM
    SALES_FLAT_QUOTE_PAYMENT
    SALES_FLAT_QUOTE_SHIPPING_RATE > quoteData.sql
```

Comment: Thanks @Jinesh, please update for categories also.

Comment: I have added it.

Comment: Thanks @Jinesh, I will try now

Comment: can you pls add for URL rewrites and quote tables as well?

Comment: hi @Jinesh, pls add for URL rewrites and quote tables data..

Comment: I have updated my answer.Please check it.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! @Jinesh..

Comment: you welcome bro

Comment: I think quote export is not correct, no tables exist like that

Comment: hi @Jinesh, this works for export, but after import, the data is imported empty, i don't see any category name and product name etc..

Comment: All product names, also other attributes like status, visibility, category name etc are imported with empty values, is there any reason, did u check this?